# Are colored graphs and red-black trees related?

Tags: graphs, compilers, red-black-trees

I've come across the concepts of colored graphs (register allocation) and red-black trees. They both seem to have this notion of "coloring", but I've never seen them being connected conceptually.

Do they have anything to do with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  They don't have anything to do with each other.

Comment: excellent answer!